# How can i checking the user identity email confirmation on razor page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I want like appear an message in _Layout when the user email not confirmation yet, such:

```
@if(User.identity.EmailConfirmed=="False")
{
<div>You must confirm...</div>
}
```

What is your solution? Thanks

Comment: I see you have `asp.net-mvc` tag so by saying `razor-pages` you meant the view of the MVC right? Just want to double check.